# How can i Get Uni Code IN Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How can in xamarin receive a Unicode or Numeric Serial Code when registering data or How to receive IP when using an Android device
please help me

Comment: Do you want to get the unique ID of Android device?

Comment: NO  I have Unit characteristic per device

Comment: I don't understand your question clearly. What is a Unicode or Numeric Serial Code?

Comment: serial number like IMEI in mobile

Comment: Look at [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54272/how-to-get-the-imei-number) thread to see if it helps.